# Create array of regex matches

Tags: java, regex

In Java, I am trying to return all regex matches to an array but it seems that you can only check whether the pattern matches something or not (boolean).

How can I use a regex match to form an array of all string matching a regex expression in a given string?

Comment: Good question. The information you seek should be part of the Java docs on Regex and Matcher. Sadly, it isn't.

Comment: A real shame. This functionality seems to exist out of the box in nearly every other language (that has regular expression support).

Answer (score 333, accepted):

*([4castle's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46859130) is better than the below if you can assume Java >= 9)*

You need to create a matcher and use that to iteratively find matches.

```
 import java.util.regex.Matcher;
 import java.util.regex.Pattern;

 ...

 List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
 Matcher m = Pattern.compile("your regular expression here")
     .matcher(yourStringHere);
 while (m.find()) {
   allMatches.add(m.group());
 }
```

After this, `allMatches` contains the matches, and you can use `allMatches.toArray(new String[0])` to get an array if you really need one.

---

You can also use `MatchResult` to write helper functions to loop over matches
since `Matcher.toMatchResult()` returns a snapshot of the current group state.

For example you can write a lazy iterator to let you do

```
for (MatchResult match : allMatches(pattern, input)) {
  // Use match, and maybe break without doing the work to find all possible matches.
}
```

by doing something like this:

```
public static Iterable<MatchResult> allMatches(
      final Pattern p, final CharSequence input) {
  return new Iterable<MatchResult>() {
    public Iterator<MatchResult> iterator() {
      return new Iterator<MatchResult>() {
        // Use a matcher internally.
        final Matcher matcher = p.matcher(input);
        // Keep a match around that supports any interleaving of hasNext/next calls.
        MatchResult pending;

        public boolean hasNext() {
          // Lazily fill pending, and avoid calling find() multiple times if the
          // clients call hasNext() repeatedly before sampling via next().
          if (pending == null && matcher.find()) {
            pending = matcher.toMatchResult();
          }
          return pending != null;
        }

        public MatchResult next() {
          // Fill pending if necessary (as when clients call next() without
          // checking hasNext()), throw if not possible.
          if (!hasNext()) { throw new NoSuchElementException(); }
          // Consume pending so next call to hasNext() does a find().
          MatchResult next = pending;
          pending = null;
          return next;
        }

        /** Required to satisfy the interface, but unsupported. */
        public void remove() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
      };
    }
  };
}
```

With this,

```
for (MatchResult match : allMatches(Pattern.compile("[abc]"), "abracadabra")) {
  System.out.println(match.group() + " at " + match.start());
}
```

yields

> ```
> a at 0
> b at 1
> a at 3
> c at 4
> a at 5
> a at 7
> b at 8
> a at 10
> ```

Comment: I wouldn't suggest using an ArrayList here since you don't know upfront the size and might want to avoid the buffer resizing. Instead, I would prefer a LinkedList -- though it's just a suggestion and doesn't make your answer less valid whatsoever.

Comment: @Liv, take the time to benchmark both `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`, the results may be surprising.

Comment: I hear what you're saying and I am aware of the execution speed and memory footprint in both cases;the problem with the ArrayList is that the default constructor creates a capacity of 10 -- if you go past that size with calls to add() you will have to bear with the memory allocation and array copy -- and that might happen a few times. Granted, if you expect just a few matches then your approach is the more efficient one; if however you find that the array "resizing" happens more than once I would suggest a LinkedList, even more so if you're dealing with a low latency app.

Comment: @Liv, If your pattern tends to produce matches with a fairly predictable size, and depending on whether the pattern matches sparsely or densely (based on the the sum of the lengths of `allMatches` vs `yourStringHere.length()`), you can probably precompute a good size for `allMatches`.  In my experience, the cost of `LinkedList` memory and iteration efficiency-wise is not usually worth it so `LinkedList` is not my default posture.  But when optimizing a hot-spot, it is definitely worth swapping list implementations to see if you get an improvement.

Comment: In Java 9, you can now use [`Matcher#results`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results--) to get a `Stream` which you can use to generate an array (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46859130/5743988)).

Comment: But ArrayList resizing is quite efficient; LinkedList is best when you have to insert/remove nodes. I don't see a problem here. Also, if you think 10 is not enough, just estimate and do `List<String> results = new ArrayList<>(100);`

Answer (score 128):

In Java 9, you can now use [`Matcher#results()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results--) to get a [`Stream<MatchResult>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) which you can use to get a list/array of matches.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.MatchResult;
```

```
String[] matches = Pattern.compile("your regex here")
                          .matcher("string to search from here")
                          .results()
                          .map(MatchResult::group)
                          .toArray(String[]::new);
                    // or .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: their is no results() method , please run this first

Comment: @Bravo Are you using Java 9? It does exist. I linked to the documentation.

Comment: :(( is there any alternative for java 8

Answer (score 26):

Java makes regex too complicated and it does not follow the perl-style. Take a look at [MentaRegex](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/me.soliveirajr/menta-regex/0.9.5) to see how you can accomplish that in a single line of Java code:

```
String[] matches = match("aa11bb22", "/(\\d+)/g" ); // => ["11", "22"]
```

Comment: Is the MentaRegex site down? When I visit http://mentaregex.soliveirajr.com/ it only says "hi"

Comment: @user64141 looks like it is

Comment: user64141 it's down now but it's available on the Internet archive http://web.archive.org/web/20130317004214/http://mentaregex.soliveirajr.com/posts/list/45.page

Comment: Four years late, but I found it at https://jar-download.com/artifacts/me.soliveirajr/menta-regex/0.9.5/source-code

Comment: Replaced the link with one to the more common mvnrepository.com...

Answer (score 16):

Here's a simple example:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexPattern);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    list.add(m.group());
}
```

(if you have more capturing groups, you can refer to them by their index as an argument of the group method. If you need an array, then use `list.toArray()`)

Comment: pattern.matches(input) does not work. You have to pass your regex pattern (again!) --> WTF Java?! pattern.matches(String regex, String input);  Do you mean pattern.matcher(input)?

Comment: @ElMac [`Pattern.matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matches-java.lang.String-java.lang.CharSequence-) is a static method, you shouldn't call it on a `Pattern` instance. `Pattern.matches(regex, input)` is simply a shorthand for `Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input).matches()`.

Answer (score 5):

From the [Official Regex Java Trails](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/test_harness.html):

```
        Pattern pattern = 
        Pattern.compile(console.readLine("%nEnter your regex: "));

        Matcher matcher = 
        pattern.matcher(console.readLine("Enter input string to search: "));

        boolean found = false;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            console.format("I found the text \"%s\" starting at " +
               "index %d and ending at index %d.%n",
                matcher.group(), matcher.start(), matcher.end());
            found = true;
        }
```

Use `find` and insert the resulting `group` at your array / List / whatever.

Answer (score 1):

```
        Set<String> keyList = new HashSet();
        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("#\\{(.*?)\\}");
        Matcher matcher = regex.matcher("Content goes here");
        while(matcher.find()) {
            keyList.add(matcher.group(1)); 
        }
        return keyList;
```