# Using the String.replaceAll function to match a regex and fetch the replacement value from a map in Java

Tags: java, regex, str-replace

I am trying to parse an expression to find out some reserved operators/strings and replace them with corresponding numeric values , which are stored in a hashmap, and display the resultant expression which has numeric values instead of the reserved strings. This is what I am trying to do:

```
String expression = "SUM_ALL(4:5,5:6)>MAX(6:7)";
Map<String, Double> functionOperators = new HashMap<String,Double>();
functionOperators.put("SUM_ALL(4:5,5:6)", 4.0);
functionOperators.put("MAX(6:7)",5.0);

expression = expression.replaceAll("(SUM_ALL|MAX)\\s*\\(\\s*([\\d:,]+)\\s*\\)",
            Double.toString(functionOperators.get(String.format("%s(%s)","$1","$2"))));
System.out.println(expression);
```

"$1" and "$2" are used to back reference the groups in the expression.

Here is the output of the same:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

whereas when I remove the fetching part (from the hashmap) and instead limit it to just a string change using the back-referenced groups, it works just fine.

```
expression = expression.replaceAll("(SUM_ALL|MAX)\\s*\\(\\s*([\\d:,]+)\\s*\\)",
            String.format("%s|%s|","$1","$2"));
```

Output:

```
SUM_ALL|4:5,5:6|>MAX|6:7|
```

I suspect that while fetching the value from the hashmap, the "$1" and "$2" variables have still not been resolved by back-referencing and hence, it is not able to locate a key corresponding to the same.

If this is true, then what method do you suggest to implement my use case where I need the replacement value from a predefined hashmap.

Comment: @JanDvorak yes it does here is the function from javadocs _replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)_

Comment: @JanDvorak - It does. Please consider my second example where it is working fine.

Comment: in first String.format("%s(%s)","$1","$2") you have used brackets and in 2nd example you have used |%s|

Comment: @BhavikShah - That is just for the sake of clarity in the 2nd example. It works fine with brackets as well.

Comment: im sorry im not good with regex is the output of _String.format("%s|%s|","$1","$2")_    is   $1($2) ?

Comment: @BhavikShah - You didn't get my point. $1 will backreference to group 1 in the regex which is SUM_ALL or MAX, and $2 will backreference to group 2 in the regex which is <function_args>. String.format only replaces the %s with the values listed in further arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know what volume of dat you have but it seems the problem is replaceAll that is not working properly because I've tried with replace and it works awesome.

```
String expression = "SUM_ALL(4:5,5:6)>MAX(6:7)<SUM_ALL(4:5,5:6)";
String mat = "";
Map<String, Double> functionOperators = new HashMap<String,Double>();
functionOperators.put("SUM_ALL(4:5,5:6)", 4.0);
functionOperators.put("MAX(6:7)",5.0);
Matcher m = 
    Pattern.compile(
            "(?:(SUM_ALL|MAX|MIN)\\(((?:\\d+:\\d+,?){1,2})\\)[+-><\\*/]?)")
            .matcher(expression);
while (m.find()) {
    mat = String.format("%s(%s)", m.group(1), m.group(2));
    expression = expression.replace(mat, functionOperators.get(mat).toString());
}
System.out.println(expression);
```

Was taken directly from your earlier example (yesterday)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was actually looking around for simpler ways of doing the same but this looks reasonable. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Your second example works because the return value of `String.format("%s(%s)","$1","$2")` is `"$1($2)"`, which is a valid second argument to the `replaceAll` method.  However, when you pass `"$1($2)"` to the `get` method of your map, it returns `null`.

To make this work, I think you'd need to separate the matching, mapping, and replacement operations.

- Get a list of all matches of your regular expression (see [Create array of regex matches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6020436/1288)).
- Get the corresponding numeric value of each match out of the map.
- Call `replaceAll` on each match.

Comment: I agree with your explanation on where the problem lies but the solution seems a little complicated. The answer by Javier looks a little more intuitive though. :)

Comment: @AbhishekJain No problem.  Javier's solution is doing basically the same, but he's processing each match as he finds them.  I agree, that is simpler than building a list.