# Get the number from Points giving in the form of a String

Tags: java, regex, string, split, point

I have a String:

```
    String str = "(25, 4) (1, -6)";
```

I want to get the individual numbers. For now, this is what I am doing:

```
    String[] strNew = str.replaceAll("\\s+","").split("-?\\D+");
```

But below is what i get:

```
25
4
1
6
```

I can't seem to get the negative on the 6. I have search on here from answers but none of the regex I found worked. Any thoughts?

Comment: You would be better off creating a regexp for a single number (`-?\d+`), then using [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6020436/240443) to extract them all. It's much cleaner and less hacky, even though Java complicates the process and makes it into a chore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you:

```
    String text = "(25, 4) (1, -6)";
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            list.add(matcher.group());
        }
        for (Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            System.out.println(iterator.next());
        }
    } catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    }
```