# Find if long string of chars contains any patterns

Tags: java, string, sequence

So I have a long string of chars for example - "wdllwdwwwlldd"
The string just contains the same chars -wld (try and guess what I'm doing ;))

The string will be quite long, approx 420 chars long.

I want to find, if they exist, any patterns in the string. 
For example if the string was - "wllddwllddwlldd" 
then it "wlldd" would be the pattern that was found.

So i kind of want to find Any repeated sequences in the string.

Having done a bit of research, suffix trees and suffix arrays seem to get mentioned a lot on these problems.

Is thst correct or is there another way to do this?

I can tell that this is quite a large task and could potentially take a long time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So are you then looking for the largest pattern that, when together, make up the entire original string?

Comment: Ideally yes, but that's not a constraint. Cause that would mean thst the string is following a pattern. But I doubt that the whole string will be, so I'd also like to know if any smaller patterns occur in the string, I.e more than 3 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you want is to extract all occurrences of some pattern from some string, did I get your point? If so, something very similar was discussed [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020384/create-array-of-regex-matches). It should at least send you in the right direction.

In your case, using regular expression such as `w+l+d+` should do the trick.

**EDIT**

Question clarified a bit more ... so the algorithm you're looking for is in a detail explained in **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452701/ukkonens-suffix-tree-algorithm-in-plain-english/9513423#9513423)**

Comment: Yeah I think we are on the same lines, the only thing is, I don't know the pattern. So it needs to see if one exists.from looking at that thread it seems that the guy knows the pattern and has a Regex for it?

Comment: @Cayongrayoo Misunderstood your question a bit - you want to know IF there are any patterns in the string, you do not use a specific one. In that case very detailed explanation on the algorithm is available in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452701/ukkonens-suffix-tree-algorithm-in-plain-english/9513423#9513423

Comment: Yeah that's correct. So suffix tree is the correct thing to do for this? That looks Luke s very helpful thread so thank you.

Comment: Okay that's great thanks. One thing I never could find when doing research is what to do once the suffix tree is created, because from what I can see, a suffix tree itself does not actually tell you if there are any patterns.