# Match text lines using Regex

Tags: java, regex

I have lines like this :

```
36600.10: [Host #255] utilization is 0.00%
36600.10: [Host #256] utilization is 21.64%
36600.10: [Host #257] utilization is 3.29%
36600.10: [Host #258] utilization is 0.94%
36600.10: [Host #260] utilization is 3.76%
36600.10: [Host #260] utilization is 1.21%
36600.10: [Host #260] utilization is 86.09%
36600.10: [Host #260] utilization is 7.32%
```

I need to get all numbers after `utilization is`. What I want is an array like this :

```
myArray[0] => 0.00,
myArray[1] => 21.64,
myArray[2] => 3.29,
myArray[3] => 0.94,
myArray[4] => 3.76,
myArray[5] => 1.21,
myArray[6] => 7.32
```

What I tried so far (it just works for first line) :

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
          String lines = "36600.10: [Host #256] utilization is 21.65% \n 36600.10: [Host #256] utilization is 91.78% \n 36600.10: [Host #256] utilization is 3.29%";
          String pattern = "(utilization is\\s)(\\d+\\.\\d*)(.*)";

          Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

          Matcher m = r.matcher(lines);
          if (m.find( )) {
             System.out.println(m.group(2));
          } else {
             System.out.println("NO MATCH");
          }

    }

}
```

Sorry I'm new in java and tried some patterns but not helped. Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: The regex is correct. All you need to do is capture the group for numbers. Although I prefer using `\\s*` instead of hard coding spaces..

Comment: @Identity1 My pattern just works for first line :(

Comment: Could you post the code using this pattern? The regex is fine.

Comment: This is what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020384/create-array-of-regex-matches

Comment: @Tunaki Post is updated

Comment: you need only answer only by regular expression or any approach will work??

Comment: @NarendraJaggi Any approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `While` loop. `If` statement will limit the match with the first occurence (Which is happening)

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
          String lines = "36600.10: [Host #256] utilization is 21.65% \n 36600.10: [Host #256] utilization is 91.78% \n 36600.10: [Host #256] utilization is 3.29%";
          String pattern = "(utilization is\\s)(\\d+\\.\\d*)(.*)";

          Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

          Matcher m = r.matcher(lines);
         while (m.find()) {
             System.out.println(m.group(2));
          } 
    }

}
```

Comment: Good answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use more than one regular expression.* And... there are several solutions. One of them is to replace the redundant text by spaces. Then use these spaces to split the string. That is to say:

*• Code:*

```java
String[] array = lines.replaceAll("(?m).*is\\s+|%\\s*", " ").trim().split("\\s+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

*• Output:*

```
[0.00, 21.64, 3.29, 0.94, 3.76, 1.21, 86.09, 7.32]
```

<sub>────────────

* By the way, [*Regular-Expressions.info - Regex Tutorial, Examples and Reference - Regexp Patterns*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) is a good place to start to learn regular expressions. [*Mastering Regular Expressions, 3rd Edition*](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do) is a highly recommended book.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using split function if you want to -

```
String lines = "36600.10: [Host #256] utilization is 21.65% \n 36600.10: [Host #256] utilization is 91.78% \n 36600.10: [Host #256] utilization is 3.29%";
        String lineArray[] = lines.split("\n");
        for(String temp:lineArray){
            String percentWithSign = temp.split("utilization is")[1];
            String percentStr  = percentWithSign.replace("%", "");
            Float percentFloat = Float.parseFloat(percentStr);
            System.out.println(percentFloat);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved without regular expression also at least in this case after seeing the pattern of your input.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("36600.10: [Host #255] utilization is 0.00%");
        list.add("36600.10: [Host #256] utilization is 21.64%");
        list.add("36600.10: [Host #255] utilization is 3.29%");
        for(int i=0 ; i<list.size() ; i++){
            String str = list.get(i);
            int start = str.lastIndexOf(" ");
            String temp = str.substring(start+1, str.length()-1);
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
```