# Extract Particular String from string in java

Tags: java

I have a string like : `String test = "A1=CA2=BOA2=RA4=OA11=O";`
Now I want output like that : `A1,A2,A2,A4,A11`

If my string like :

```
String test = "[HEADER_1] [DATA] \n A10=T,(\"Re-N RO-25 M-N P-N (B)\"),1.0:0.8,R=25.0 F-7.829215,-4.032765 A20=B,R2,M=XY,R=29.999999999999996 F564.997550,669.454680";


public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "A1=CA2=BOA2=RA4=O";
    String data[] = test.split("[A-a]\\d{1,100}=");

    for (String str : data) {
      System.out.println("Split data:"+str);
    }      
}
```

What would be the regex for  that?

Comment: What's the problem with the code that you have already written?

Comment: your output should contain only start from A or other letters will be there lik B1,b2, BB1,AA1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not use split for that. The regex for the parts that you want is `/a\d+/i`. If you use this and the Solution from [Create array of regex matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020384/create-array-of-regex-matches) to collect all matches in a list, you can easily create the desired output.

Converted the Regex in Java-Parlor:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "A1=CA2=BOA2=RA4=OA11=O";
    List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(a\\d+)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(test);

    while (m.find()) {
       allMatches.add(m.group());
    }
}
```

allMatches now contains A1 A2 A2 A4 A11

Comment: I didn't vote you down, but I would not attempt to use a single regex here.  The reason is that regex does not work so well in the case of an unbounded number of matches, which is precisely what the OP has.

Comment: Could you explain which cases you mean?

Comment: Your regex won't work, just try using it.  You'd be better off going with `String.split()` first and then matching against each part.

Comment: I still don't get it: http://rubular.com/r/OGxKqzua4s matches all the OP wants. Which are the cases where it does not work?

Comment: If you are sure, then post a working snippet of Java code so that the OP may test it.

Comment: I added a sample program

Comment: It looks better now.  So you are looping over the string and finding matches.  I think the initial confusion was because you  made it look like you were using a single flat regex for everything.

Answer (score 0):

The regex you are probably looking for is `[A-a][0-9]{1,2}`.

So in Java,

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


String test = "A1=CA2=BOA2=RA4=OA11=O";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[A-a][0-9]{1,2}").matcher(test);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.print(m.group(0)+",");
}
```

Comment: @RahulBhawar.  You are most definitely right!  But you didn't bother to read the question to see that that isn't a use case.  Furthermore, the OPs broken regex has the intent to match numbers `1-100`.

Answer (score 0):

```
String test = "A1=CA2=BOA2=RA4=OA11=O";
String[] parts = test.split("=");
String[] output = new String[parts.length];
for (int i=0; i < parts.length; ++i) {
    output[i] = parts[i].replaceAll("^.*(A\\d*)$", "$1");
    System.out.println(parts[i] + " becomes " + output[i]);
}
```

**Output:**

```
A1 becomes A1
CA2 becomes A2
BOA2 becomes A2
RA4 becomes A4
OA11 becomes A11
O becomes O
```

Comment: "OA11 becomes OA11" - Shouldn't `OA11` go to `A11`?

Comment: @intboolstring Good call.  You posted so quickly, I had no time for thorough testing ^ ^

Comment: I can not split using '=' because my string contains multiple times '='. For example "A1=C,R=25A2=BOA2=RA4=OA11=O";

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty I think you are confused on how String.split() works. It will split up the string using all = signs, no matter how many appear.  Please test my code to see for yourself.  You should be able to just cut and paste it.