# Find markdown image syntax in String in Java

Tags: java, regex, markdown

I've a long text in Java, which contains at least one markdown image syntax. If there're `N` markdown image syntax, I will need to split the string into `N+1` substrings and store them in an array of String, call `texts`. For example, I've the following text

```
Hello world!
![Alt text](/1/2/3.jpg)
Hello Stack Overflow!
```

Then `Hello world!\n` will be stored in position 0 and `\nHello Stack Overflow!` will be stored in position 1. For my question, we can assume that

- The *Alt text* part contains only character A-Z, a-z and blank space.
- The *URL* part contains only digits 0-9 and slash `/`. Its extension will only be `.jpg`. Other extension will not exist.

My question is how to split the text ? Do we need a java regular expression, such as `*![*](*.jpg)` ?

Comment: A regex, sure - why not. Is your regex notation different than the standard one?

Comment: No, my regex notation supposes to be same as the standard one. If there's error, it's my fault. (I don't know much about regular expression)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this (ready to copy-paste):

`"!\\[[^\\]]+\\]\\([^)]+\\)"`

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020384/create-array-of-regex-matches) for info about how to get the matches.

"Untainted" version:
`!\[[^\]]+\]\([^)]+\)`

## Explanation

- `!` literally `!`
- `\[` escaped `[`
- `[^\]]+` as many not `]`s as possible
- `\]\(` escaped `](`
- `[^)]+` as many not `)`s as possible
- `\)` escaped `)`

Comment: @MincongHuang Added! I explained the "untainted" version.

Comment: Wonderful explanation. I've learnt a lot from it, thank you @Laurel

Comment: Actually, the escaped content (markdown) are useful for me. Can I get them and put them into other string array ?

Answer (score 0):

This is my way

````
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
     String str = "}```![imageName](/sword?SwordControllerName=KMFileDownloadController&id=c60b6c5a8d9b46baa1dc266910db462d \"imageName\")#### JSON data";
     Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\[.*\\]\\((.*)\\)").matcher(str);
     while (m.find()) {
         allMatches.add(m.group(1).split(" ")[0]);
     }
     //print "/sword?SwordControllerName=KMFileDownloadController&id=c60b6c5a8d9b46baa1dc266910db462d"
     for(String s:allMatches){
         System.out.println(s);
     }
  }
}
````

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 0):

```
!\[[^\]]*?\]\([^)]+\)
```

That way Alt Text can stay empty - though it makes no sense