# RegEx to extract text between tags in Java

Tags: java, regex

I need to extract the values after `:70:` in the following text file using RegEx. Value may contain line breaks as well.

My current solution is to extract the string between `:70:` and `:` but this always returns only one match, the whole text between the first `:70:` and last `:`.

```
:32B:xxx,
:59:yyy
something
:70:ACK1
ACK2
:21:something
:71A:something
:23E:something
value
:70:ACK2
ACK3
:71A:something
```

How can I achive this using Java? Ideally I want to iterate through all values, i.e.

`ACK1\nACK2`,
`ACK2\nACK3`

Thanks :)

Edit: What I'm doing right now,

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=:70:)(.*)(?=\n)", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);
while (matcher.find()) {
   System.out.println(matcher.group())
}
```

Comment: @Jens added my current solution.

Comment: do you want the `32B` or only `32` from your input ?

Comment: @PavneetSingh I only need `ACK1\nACK2` and `ACK2\nACK3`. Don't care about anything else. ;)

Comment: If you are sure that `:` is always and only used as separator, you could simply use `(?<=:70:)([^:]*)`. This might catch a trailing newline, but you should be able to trim it off.

Comment: @SebastianProske works! thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
String data = ""
    + ":32B:xxx,\n"
    + ":59:yyy\n"
    + "something\n"
    + ":70:ACK1\n"
    + "ACK2\n"
    + ":21:something\n"
    + ":71A:something\n"
    + ":23E:something\n"
    + "value\n"
    + ":70:ACK2\n"
    + "ACK3\n"
    + ":71A:something\n";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(":70:(.*?)\\s*:", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);
while (matcher.find())
    System.out.println("found="+ matcher.group(1));
```

result:

```
found=ACK1
ACK2
found=ACK2
ACK3
```

Answer (score -1):

You need a loop to do this.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexPattern);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
Matcher m = p.matches(input);
while (m.find()) {
    list.add(m.group());
}
```

As seen here [Create array of regex matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020384/create-array-of-regex-matches)

Comment: I'm already doing this but `matcher.find()` only finds a single match. :( Please also check my current solution. I added it to the question.

Comment: I don't see a loop in the solution provided.

Comment: I have the `while (matcher.find()) {}` after creating the `Matcher`. I think the issue is more related to my RegEx because I only get one match.

Comment: If your loop is empty than you aren't putting your results together. The `list.add(m.group())` is important.

Comment: No my loop is not empty; I'm using the value returned from `m.group()` -.- Updated the question to make this clear.