# Regex for phrase not running as expected in Java altrough was tested online

Tags: java, regex

I have devised a Regex that uses the following pattern: [^.!?"]+ , in order to retrieve sentences and phrases from a given text. The pattern was tested on multiple online Regex validator sites like https://regexr.com/ and works as expected.

On Java code when I try to use the same Regex the result is not as expected.

```
String a =" fjefjeijfeijfei? ejfn rwfnrujnfijnf rfjnwrjrfnjrfn, rjfirjnfi4, rijijf.";
a.split("[^.?!\"]+");
```

The result is:

```
fjefjeijfeijfei? ejfn rwfnrujnfijnf rfjnwrjrfnjrfn, rjfirjnfi4, rijijf.
```

Instead of:

- fjefjeijfeijfei
- ejfn rwfnrujnfijnf rfjnwrjrfnjrfn, rjfirjnfi4,
  rijijf

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Remove the caret `^`.

Comment: Use `[^.?!"]+` with *matching* code, not splitting. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6020436/3832970. Note that regex101 may [generate Java code for you](https://regex101.com/r/4p05ss/1/codegen?language=java).