# Regex to split string and preserve content within double quotes

Tags: java, regex

Yes I know this has been asked a lot but there is no solution I've found for what exactly I'm trying to do. So please allow me to explain what my problem is.

I need to find a way so tokenize a string based on ',' , '.', white space, and between quotes without applying other regex rules between the quotes.

**Allow this '[]' to represent a single space for these examples.**

Suppose I have a string like this:

```
ADD[]r2,[]r3
```

Now with a regex like this:

```
((?<=\s)|(?=\s+))|((?<=,))|(?=\.)
```

I can split the string like so:

```
1: ADD
2: []
3: r2,
4: []
5: r3
```

This is what I want.

Now suppose I have a string like this:

```
"ADD[]r2,[]r3"[]"foo[]bar"
```

Now with a regex like this:

```
(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)
```

I can split the string like this:

```
1: "ADD[]r2,[]r3"
2: []
3: "foo[]bar"
```

But if I had a string like this:

```
ADD[]r2,[]r3[]"ADD[]r2,[]r3"
```

And used a regex like this:

```
(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)((?<=\s)|(?=\s+))|((?<=,))|(?=\.)
```

I would end up with something like this:

```
1:ADD
2:[]
3:r2,
4:[]
5:r3
6:[]
7:"Add[]r2,
8:[] r3"
```

But what I want is this:

```
1:ADD
2:[]
3:r2,
4:[]
5:r3
6:[]
7:"Add[]r2,[]r3"
```

Is it possible to do this with a regex? Or do I need to do something more complex? What I'm trying to do is basically make a regex to split up code syntax. I just need a way to split up a line like I have described.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Example drive code of what I'm trying to do

```
 String line = "ADD r2, r3 \"ADD r2, r3\"";
        String[] arrLine = line.substring(0, line.length()).split("(?=(?:[^\\\"]*\\\"[^\\\"]*\\\")*[^\\\"]*$)((?<=\\s)|(?=\\s+))|((?<=,))|(?=\\.)");

        for(int i = 0; i < arrLine.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(arrLine[i]);
        }
```

Comment: Like this? `"[^"]*"|\h|[^\s"]+` https://regex101.com/r/5y77KP/1

Comment: Yes, or [`"[^"]*"|[^\s"]+|\s+`](https://regex101.com/r/Qanl1i/1)

Comment: @Thefourthbird no. See the edit I made to show you how I'm splitting the string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew See edit I made.

Comment: @boardkeystown Why don't you match it instead? See https://ideone.com/d95sbB

Comment: You should use an *extraction* approach here, see [Create array of regex matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020384/create-array-of-regex-matches)

Comment: Regexes aren't very good for problems like this. The next thing you'll probably want is for `\"` to be a non-terminating string char. Then things get _really_ complicated.  Imo it's better to give up early and write a finite-automaton-based scanner that will handle all future contingencies easily without solving regex puzzles.

Comment: @Gene you are right... I would need to account for that case at some point. What do you mean by a finite-automaton-based scanner? I'm going to Google it right after I finish this comment. I know what a finite automaton is but never used it for anything in java.

Comment: Personally, for something like this I'd write a simple 2-state (IDLE, IN_QUOTE) 4-input (DOT, COMMA, QUOTE, OTHER) DFA and process the input one character at a time. I have a feeling you don't completely know the grammar you're trying to parse, and I'd much rather maintain a DFA than horribly complex regular expressions. (A DFA would be a lot faster too, but that's premature optimization :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I see a problem like this in general I immediately think to break it down into two or more simpler problems. The other thing that occurs to me is that your problem may get more complicated. It might be worth thinking about ANTLR here.

Comment: You are right I needed to break it down into smaller steps. I had to write my own tokenizer to do exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using split, you can match either from an opening till closing double quote, or match whitespace characters, or match all characters except whitespaces and double quotes.

In Java you can use `\h` to match a horizontal whitespace char, or use `\s` to match a whitespace char that could also match a newline.

```
"[^"]*"|\h+|[^\h"]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NWIWTf/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/d95sbB)

In Java

```
String regex = "\"[^\"]*\"|\\h+|[^\\h\"]+";
String string = "ADD r2, r3 \"ADD r2, r3\"";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Output

```
ADD
 
r2,
 
r3
 
"ADD r2, r3"
```

Comment: The reason I need the split is because I have a larger algo that requires all of those things to be split by white space and account for a case if there is not white space. 

Also yours would not handle the case if "ADD r2,r3" b/c r2,r3 would be 1 split and not 2.

Comment: @boardkeystown This `"ADD r2,r3" b/c r2,r3` contains 2 spaces not between double quotes. Why should there be 1 split and where should the split be?

Comment: You could extend it for example not matching newlines between the double quotes and matching and escaped double quote within the double quotes. https://regex101.com/r/4Nu2Qu/1

Comment: I want to thank you for the suggestion. However doing it this way did not work out for my needs.